# bootstrap-typeahead requires 2 taps to select on ios7

Tags: jquery, safari, ios7, bootstrap-typeahead

Using bootstrap-typeahead.js v2.3.2 to autocomplete on Safari iOS7 requires tapping twice to select an item from the list. The first time it hides the keyboard and marks the option as active, but the click doesn't go through until you tap it again.

Other browsers or phones or even older versions of iOS don't have this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Found out that tapping an option causes the text field to 'blur' (so far so good), but for some reason (or bug) the original click event never gets fired. Only the mouseenter.

A quick fix was call the 'click' function from the 'blur' handler if something has been "mouseover-ed". This doesn't seem to cause any problems to other browsers that might call the 'click' function twice.

Just add the line with the comment below. This chunk would be lines 265-269:

```
, blur: function (e) {
  this.focused = false
  if (!this.mousedover && this.shown) this.hide()
  else if (this.mousedover) this.click(e) // fix ios7 missing click on blur
}
```

Hope this helps somebody with the same problem or other libraries that also don't get a click after a blur on iOS7.